# Spring 3 - Stop serializing an autowired bean

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a session object which contains a reference to another object that I do not wish to serialize. 
Is it possible to do so using annotations?

```
@Component
 public class Model implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark it with `transient`, though it would be `null` after deserialization.

Comment: do you mean private transient Validator validator?

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the validation out of the POJO into a helper class.  You could use the validation annotations from javax.validation describe in JSR-303.  Here is a howto link:
http://www.openscope.net/2010/02/08/spring-mvc-3-0-and-jsr-303-aka-javax-validation/